# Allocate memory for a variable inside a function only once in a loop

Tags: c++, memory-management

Let's have a function `func` which allocates memory for `vec`. Also let's `func` is called many times in a loop.

```
void func ()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.resize(someNumber);
}

for (int i=0; i<someNumber; ++i)
{
    func ();
}
```

How I can allocate memory for `vec` only once in a loop?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `static` keyword?

Comment: Why do you care? It's a local variable, it goes on the stack. The allocation itself is literally free (even though the construction of the object is not).

Comment: @Beta: That will cause miserable failures in a threaded environment.

Comment: @Jon: The memory allocated for storage of the vector's contents is on the heap, not the stack.

Comment: @Jon, what do you mean by the allocation itself is literally free?

Comment: Both "heap" and "stack" are wrong terms when talking about C++. Correct terms are "dynamic" and "automatic" storage.

Comment: @Griwes Not at all -- they are still completely relevant.

Comment: @cdhowie, standard does not define them, only "dynamic" and "automatic" storage, hence "stack" and "heap" are not well defined in C++ context, hence they are incorrect.

Comment: @Griwes Technical illdefined of course, but representative of the vast majority of actual implementations and usually well understood. That said, I mostly try to use the words from the standard.

Comment: @shibli You need to tell us a little more about *why* you want do this and what else you are doing with the `vector` inside `func()`.  What are you concerned about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Beta said, every time the function `func()` is called a new vector is created and is destroyed when the function exits. If you want to have a single vector which gets resized which each call, you may want to do something like

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for (int i=0; i<someNumber; ++i)
{
    vec.resize(i);
}
```

or you can direcly initialise your vector with the max memory you will need as

```
std::vector<int> vec(someNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions I can see.  One is to have the function take a reference to an `std::vector<int>` that it can use.

```
void func (std::vector<int> & vec)
{
    vec.resize(someNumber);
}
```

Another possibility is to create a functor that uses a private vector, and can therefore reuse the allocation, assuming it is called multiple times.

```
class SomeFunctor
{
public:
    void operator()();

private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
}

void SomeFunctor::operator()()
{
    vec.resize(someNumber);
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
SomeFunctor func;

for (int i=0; i<someNumber; ++i)
{
    func ();
}
```

Note that calling `resize()` on the vector means that the vector will allocate new storage for the existing elements, copy the existing elements over, and deallocate the old storage.  This defeats the entire purpose of holding onto a vector object, as the vector's internal allocation will *never* be reused!  Consider using `reserve()` instead, which will never shrink (but may enlarge) the allocation.

The optimal solution might be none of these approaches, but something far simpler.  Your example code has not given enough detail to know if these approaches will be beneficial.

---

As a side note, remember that premature optimization is a bad thing.  Code first, then run a profiler and see where the bottlenecks are -- usually they will be around collecting user input or other things like network and disk I/O.  I'm not saying that you shouldn't try to predict possible bottlenecks and engineer around them, but don't excessively worry about every possible function call and allocation/deallocation.

If this is a working application and not a prototype, run a profiler.  You are very likely to find that any bottlenecks lie elsewhere.

Comment: That's not true- it won't resize if it already holds enough elements.

Comment: @DeadMG If it holds exactly the same number, yes.  In all other cases it will reallocate.